# Why is my ng-view animation not working?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-view

I'm trying to give my ng-view an animation, I have exactly the same code as the example and I so no error or anything.

This is my html code:

```
<div ng-view class="slidedown">
    <!--Insert templates-->

</div>
```

, css code:

```
.slidedown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slidedown.ng-enter,
.slidedown.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slidedown.ng-enter {
    top: -100%;
}
.slidedown.ng-enter-active {
    top: 0;
}
.slidedown.ng-leave {
    top: 0;
}
.slidedown.ng-leave-active {
    top: 100%;
}
```

and yes I have defined the source files:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="assets/Css/ng-view.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- JS -->
<script src="componenten/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="componenten/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

So I really don't get it why it isn't working.
Am I missing something?

Comment: provide your code on plunker

Comment: and you included module dependency: `['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']`?

Comment: Thank you @UR, while I was making the Plunkr I already fixed. I forgot to  include module dependency `['ngAnimate']`. So thank you for letting me make the Plunkr.

Comment: @dfsq Exactly that! While I was making the Plunkr I saw I was missing it.
If you want to you can make an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Cool, you see why it is important to prepare minimal demo, in many cases you figure out the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was that I forgot to include module dependency `['ngAnimate']`.